# Added a drop down triangle to my UIButton with a subclass, how can I prevent it from stretching when I change the title?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a simple `UIButton` subclass to add a drop down triangle to the default UIButtons. I drop a `UIView` in my view controller's title view in my Storyboard, and then add the button subclass to that view in Storyboard. The only thing I do with Auto Layout in the Storyboard is center it vertically and horizontally.

Here's the code:

```
class DropDownButton: UIButton {   
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setImage(UIImage(named: "drop-down-triangle"), forState: .Normal)

        sizeToFit()

        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageRectForContentRect(bounds).width - 17.0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: titleRectForContentRect(bounds).width, bottom: -2, right: 0)
    }
}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

In code I sometimes change the title with:

```
dropDownButton.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
```

Which causes it to look like this:

[image]

What is causing this? How do I stop it from stretching?

Comment: Try calling `sizeToFit` or `layoutIfNeeded` immediately after you change the text

Comment: Did you try setting this  imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; on your imageView. ?

Comment: You can try making the most left pixel only stretchable and use this image as 9 patch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class DropDownButton: UIButton {   
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setImage(UIImage(named: "drop-down-triangle"), forState: .Normal)

        sizeToFit()

        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -imageRectForContentRect(bounds).width - 17.0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: **static value here**, bottom: -2, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using storyboard then set the properties as shown in screen shot. Or you can set them programatically.

In the code you can use like this:

```
[privacyButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
[privacyButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this will help.[image]